# How do I implement a circular buffer in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, circular-buffer

I have a matrix for instance

```
a=[12,2,4,67,8,9,23]
```

and I would like a code that appends a value say 45 to it and removes the first value '12'
so in essence I want to make

```
a = [2,4,67,8,9,23,45]
```

I want to work with regular matrices not numpy matrices so I can't use hstack or vstack
How do I do this in python? Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: This is not a sliding window; this is a circular buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
a = a[1:] + [45]
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Should have thought of it, I'm just a beginner in python. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, but FogleBird's answer is in fact more efficient if performance is a concern at all.

Answer (score 13):

Use a deque.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.deque(maxlen=7)
>>> d.extend([12,2,4,67,8,9,23])
>>> d.append(45)
>>> print d
deque([2, 4, 67, 8, 9, 23, 45], maxlen=7)
```

Comment: Thanks but what does deque mean? And thanks for the answer but I think I will go with Marian's answers it is simpler

Comment: @user17151 deque = double-ended queue. If you have 20 values, it doesn't matter which you use. If you have 2 million values, the deque is the qay to go rather than a mere list.

Comment: @user17151: that's fine but a deque is more efficient since it won't have to copy the entire data structure each time an element is appended.

Comment: This makes the append operation more efficient, but accessing elements in the middle of the data structure is *less* efficient with a deque  than with a list (O(n) vs O(1)).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
a=[12,2,4,67,8,9,23]
a.append(45)
a.pop(0)
```